# master/worker in sql server without locks

Tags: java, sql-server, locking

What would be the best way to implement master-worker approach using ms sql-server? I.e., one java process (**master**) puts data to the table(s) and one or more java processes (**workers**) retrieve this data from table(s), processes it and updates some fields in the records being retrieved.

Which approach will be preferable to implement in order to avoid sql-server locks?

*Approach 1:*
Single **master** inserts data into one table and one **worker** retrieves it, processes and updates status flag in the records being retrieved.

*Approach 2:*
Each **worker** has it's own table and single **master** distributes the data across the tables. Each **worker** retrieves data from it's own table, processes it and updates status flag.

As fas as I concerned there is **NO** way to enforce sql-server the way to lock the records. It is possible only to give some hints. If so, will the second approach be acceptable?

EDIT:

@Matt Ball: 
Java process could be just a thread. And locks are not thread locks but sql-server record/page/table locks.

And I want to avoid the sql-server locks or reduce them in order to raise the performance.

Thanks.

Comment: When you say "Java process," do you mean a thread, or a JVM instance which is completely separate from a set of "worker" JVM instances? More importantly, though, **what's wrong with using DB locks?**

Comment: See [Using tables as Queues](http://rusanu.com/2010/03/26/using-tables-as-queues/) I think this is what you are trying to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't avoid DB locks, this is how ACID properties are guaranteed in most comercial relational engines. That being said, what you desire is indeed, as Martin pointed out, a queue.. Queues are the cornerstone of the producer-consumer or master-worker patterns. Queues backed by tables are feasable and can scale quite high: hundreds of concurent enqueue/dequeue operations are quite feasable. The article Martin links goes into details explaining how to do it.

You do not need separate queues per worker, nor per master.. Separating into a table per worker will only create operational hurdles: how many tables? What if I add a worker? what if a worker is overloaded, how do I transfer it's pending work to a different one? How do I shut down workers on idle periods? One single queue is the best approach, because you can add/reduce the numebr of workers dynamically w/o doing expensive DB operations (Add new table, transfer existing work etc). A single table will also allow for multiple workers to load-balance the work among themselves naturarly.

While it is technically possible, I would recommend against doing a state based table (state 'to process', state 'processed'). Use instead a true queue, from where records are deleted when a worker picks it up. If you need a persisted state, use a table for state and a queue for events. The enqueued info should contain the id to process.